# Failed to set a credential for network based account

Tags: macos

We want to assign credentials to network based accounts according to the following Apple kbase: [How to allow administration of OS X from network-based accounts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202112)

```
dseditgroup -o edit -n /Local/Default -u localadmin -p -a networkuser -t user admin
Failed to set credentials
```

Can anyone advice what's wrong and how to improve it?

OS X 10.10

Comment: Your question is unclear: The above command allows AD domain admins  or enterprise admins etc. to administer OS X? Do you want this?

Comment: We want to allow network users or groups to have administrator access with this command. Clients are OS X 10.10 and the server is Windows server 2010 for AD.

Comment: Windows Server 2008, Windows Home Server 2011 or Windows Server 2012? Do you use a proper names for localadmin and networkuser? Did you  "join" the AD with the OS X Clients?